# How to get the "python setup.py" submit information on freshmeat?

Tags: python, setuptools

This can submit information about your software on pypi:

```
python setup.py register
```

But there is not a similar command for submitting information to freshmeat.
How could I write a distutils.Command that would let me do the following?

```
python setup.py freshmeat-submit
```

Comment: Hmmm... what happens if I download your package and run this command?

Comment: The way 'python setup.py register' works is that anyone can register any package the first time, and after that the particular package name can only be updated by the account that originally registered it.

Comment: The "python setup.py register" also updates the information about the release.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy; I'd say freshmeat API will be straightforward.

For python site, for setup() function in setup.py, give this argument:

```
entry_points = {
    'distutils.commands' : [
        'freshmeat-submit = freshsubmitter.submit:SubmitToFreshMeat',
    ],
},
```

where freshsubmitter is your new pakcage, submit is module inside it and SubmitToFreshMeat is from distutils.command.config.config subclass.

Please be aware that entry_points are global, so you should distribute your command as separate package; bundling it with every package will cause conflicts.